# Set up nvidia drivers on mobile sli configuration

Tags: x11, graphics, nvidia, slackware

I have been trying to get xfce running on my slackware install for a while now, but no matter which graphics driver I use it always fails with the no screens found error. I can run it at a significantly reduced resolution using the stock options, but that isn't acceptable for most purposes. Has anyone had success setting up a mobile sli configuration in linux? I am able run  Ubuntu with correct resolution settings, but that was working by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by first installing the legacy 304.08 driver and then upgrading to the 319 driver. I'm not completely sure why that worked, but every thing is properly configured now.